# PHP Trait colliding constructor

Tags: php, traits

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I did search for the answer previously.

I'm struggling to overload a method defined in a trait. It throws a fatal error:

`Fatal error: Configuration has colliding constructor definitions coming from traits in Configuration.php on line 18`

**Their Class**

```php
<?php

namespace Theirs\Package;

use Theirs\TheirTrait;

class Configration
{
    use TheirTrait;
}
```

**My Class**

```php
<?php

namespace My\Package;

use Theirs\Package\Configuration as BaseConfiguration;
use My\Trait\MyTrait;

class Configuration extends BaseConfiguration
{
    use MyTrait;
}
```

**My Trait**

```php
use Theirs\TheirTrait as BaseSomeTrait;

trait MyTrait
{
    use BaseSomeTrait;

    protected function someMethod($something)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can resolve the constructor collision like this.

```
trait MyTrait {

    use BaseSomeTrait{
        BaseSomeTrait::__construct as private __otherConstruct;
    }

    public function __construct(/* maybe params here*/)
    {
        // maybe other code
        $this->__otherConstruct(/* maybe params here*/);
        // maybe other code
    }
}
```

if MyClass has a constructor as well you need to do it there additionally, or maybe only there if MyTrait has no constructor...

Comment: Thanks, I was doing this initially. Turns out it was another class deeper down that was bringing in the dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both `Theirs\TheirTrait\Configration` and `Theirs\Package\Configuration` have a constructor, and the constructor signatures are incompatible. (But without the code of both, it’s hard to tell.)

If `Theirs\Package\Configuration` is really intended to be used with `Theirs\TheirTrait\Configration`, you should write them a bug report. Otherwise, I guess there should be some documentation on how to use the class and the trait in your code so that they don’t produce errors.